# amsmath & \tasks environment: How to align multi-step equation solution on "="

Tags: align, amsmath, line-spacing, tasks

Using amsmath with the \tasks environment.

@orelo fixed 2 problems:

1. reduced line spacing
2. partially fixed alignment on the "=" symbol.

I probably wasn't clear enough in my OP re: desired alignment.

Thank you!

mwe:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{framed} %box para
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
%\everymath{\displaystyle}
%\usepackage{bm}%bold equation
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % removes paragraph indentation

\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algegra II: Assignment: 9-E}
       {}
       {Due 02/24/2023} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
  %\makebox[\textwidth]%{Name:\enspace\hrulefill}\par
  \vspace{4mm}
  \fbox{\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-4\fboxsep-4\fboxrule}{
    \textbf {Find all solutions (real and imaginary/complex roots) to each quadratic equation. Simplify answers.}
    %\par
    %\bigskip

  }}}\par
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}

\begin{document}
\pagetop

\settasks{
    after-item-skip=5em,    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=2em,
    item-indent=3em,
    label=(\arabic*),
    column-sep=2em
}
\begin{tasks}(2)
%Prob #1
\task \(\begin{aligned}[t]
&3x^2+27=0 \\
& \hspace{2em}\begin{aligned}[t]
&3x^2=-27 \\
&x^2= -9 \\   &\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt{-9}\\
&\sqrt{x^2}=i\sqrt{9}\\
&x=\pm3i
\end{aligned}
        \end{aligned}\)
%Problem #2
\task \(\begin{aligned}[t]
&x^2=-12 \\
& \hspace{2em}\begin{aligned}[t]
&\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt{-12} \\
&\sqrt{x^2}=i\sqrt{12}\\
&\sqrt{x^2}=i\sqrt{4}\sqrt{3}\\
&x=\pm2i\sqrt{3}
\end{aligned}
        \end{aligned}\)
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I understand equations should be left aligned at a task label. So you would need to use inline math mode. `aligned` environments can be nested if you need to apply a more complex alignment.

```latex
%Prob #1
\task \(\begin{aligned}[t]
            &(-2+3i)+(5-2i) \\
            & \hspace{2em}  \begin{aligned}[t]
                                &= (-2+5)+(3i-2i) \\
                                &= 3+i
                            \end{aligned}
        \end{aligned}\)
```

[image]

---

EDIT in order to respond to OP's request: *Any idea how to solve the floating equal sign issue shown in the new image?*

The edited image is actually a much simpler case than the one before. Each align(ed)-like environment form groups of 2 columns with right/left alignments; the two columns are separated by `&`. Each group (if there are more) is also separated by `&`. For instance below is an example of three groups and 6 columns all together:

```
L & R   &   L & R   &  L & R ... %etc.
```

In your case the image contain just one group of two columns. You only need one ampersand before each `=`. As mentioned before, you can nest `aligned` environments to form more complex structures but it is not required in your case. There's more info in [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) user manual. It has much better explanation than I can give.

So, this snippet:

```latex
%Prob #1
\task \(
    \begin{aligned}[t]
        3x^2+27 &=0 \\
        3x^2 &=-27 \\
        x^2 &= -9 \\
        \sqrt{x^2} &=\sqrt{-9}\\
        \sqrt{x^2} &=i\sqrt{9}\\
        x &=\pm3i
    \end{aligned}\)
```

produces this expression:

[image]

I hope it's clearer why everything is aligned at `=`.

Below is the full code. I had to comment a few lines: some caused error, and other were simply not required for the MWE.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
% \usepackage{amssymb}
% \usepackage{framed} %box para
% \usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
%\everymath{\displaystyle}
%\usepackage{bm}%bold equation

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % removes paragraph indentation

% \pagestyle{head}
% \header{Algegra II: Assignment: 9-E}
       % {}
       % {Due 02/24/2023} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
  %\makebox[\textwidth]%{Name:\enspace\hrulefill}\par
  \vspace{4mm}
  \fbox{\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-4\fboxsep-4\fboxrule}{
    \textbf {Find all solutions (real and imaginary/complex roots) to each quadratic equation. Simplify answers.}
    %\par
    %\bigskip

  }}}\par
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}


\begin{document}
\pagetop

\settasks{
    after-item-skip=5em,    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=2em,
    item-indent=3em,
    label=(\arabic*),
    column-sep=2em
}
\begin{tasks}(2)
%Prob #1
\task \(
    \begin{aligned}[t]
        3x^2+27 &=0 \\
        3x^2 &=-27 \\
        x^2 &= -9 \\
        \sqrt{x^2} &=\sqrt{-9}\\
        \sqrt{x^2} &=i\sqrt{9}\\
        x &=\pm3i
    \end{aligned}\)
%Problem #2
\task \(
    \begin{aligned}[t]
        x^2 &= -12 \\
        \sqrt{x^2} &= \sqrt{-12} \\
        \sqrt{x^2} &= i\sqrt{12}\\
        \sqrt{x^2} &= i\sqrt{4}\sqrt{3}\\
        x &= \pm2i\sqrt{3}
    \end{aligned}\)
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks especially for adjusting the line spacing. I have marked post as "solved". Will use this as a worksheet template for my maths students.

Comment: Can anyone explain why I can't insert an image into my edited OP? The OP contained a screen shot that I wanted to replace to reflect output to new code revision.

Comment: I think I sorted your image. I suspect a code block was not formatted correctly and the parser couldn't see the image placeholder. It seems to be working now

Comment: Awesome fix with my image. Any idea how to solve the floating equal sign issue shown in the new image? Thanks!